# ASP.NET Master pages <script> not runing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a page with multiple Updatepannel that are all visible false and I show them one after another when you click a button.
I want to use bootstrap datetime picker but my problem is that the script is not rune by the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
 </script>
```

If I run this in the console all is working.
Any ideas on how to force the run of the script ?

As requested :

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
init[1]0: documentcontext: documentURL: "http://localhost:52261/Dashboard.aspx"activeElement: bodyalinkColor: ""all: HTMLAllCollection[520]anchors: HTMLCollection[0]applets: HTMLCollection[0]baseURI: "http://localhost:52261/Dashboard.aspx"bgColor: ""body: bodycharacterSet: "UTF-8"charset: "UTF-8"childElementCount: 1childNodes: NodeList[2]children: HTMLCollection[1]compatMode: "CSS1Compat"contentType: "text/html"cookie: ""cphNavigation_imgProfile: undefinedcurrentScript: nulldefaultView: WindowdesignMode: "off"dir: ""doctype: <!DOCTYPE html>documentElement: htmldocumentURI: "http://localhost:52261/Dashboard.aspx"domain: "localhost"embeds: HTMLCollection[0]fgColor: ""firstChild: <!DOCTYPE html>firstElementChild: htmlfonts: FontFaceSetforms: HTMLCollection[1]head: headhidden: falseimages: HTMLCollection[1]implementation: DOMImplementationinputEncoding: "UTF-8"isConnected: truejQuery19107336506808681962: 1lastChild: htmllastElementChild: htmllastModified: "02/17/2017 11:51:13"linkColor: ""links: HTMLCollection[68]location: LocationnextSibling: nullnodeName: "#document"nodeType: 9nodeValue: nullonabort: nullonauxclick: nullonbeforecopy: nullonbeforecut: nullonbeforepaste: nullonblur: nulloncancel: nulloncanplay: nulloncanplaythrough: nullonchange: nullonclick: nullonclose: nulloncontextmenu: nulloncopy: nulloncuechange: nulloncut: nullondblclick: nullondrag: nullondragend: nullondragenter: nullondragleave: nullondragover: nullondragstart: nullondrop: nullondurationchange: nullonemptied: nullonended: nullonerror: nullonfocus: nulloninput: nulloninvalid: nullonkeydown: nullonkeypress: nullonkeyup: nullonload: nullonloadeddata: nullonloadedmetadata: nullonloadstart: nullonmousedown: nullonmouseenter: nullonmouseleave: nullonmousemove: nullonmouseout: nullonmouseover: nullonmouseup: nullonmousewheel: nullonpaste: nullonpause: nullonplay: nullonplaying: nullonpointercancel: nullonpointerdown: nullonpointerenter: nullonpointerleave: nullonpointerlockchange: nullonpointerlockerror: nullonpointermove: nullonpointerout: nullonpointerover: nullonpointerup: nullonprogress: nullonratechange: nullonreadystatechange: nullonreset: nullonresize: nullonscroll: nullonsearch: nullonseeked: nullonseeking: nullonselect: nullonselectionchange: nullonselectstart: nullonshow: nullonstalled: nullonsubmit: nullonsuspend: nullontimeupdate: nullontoggle: nullonvolumechange: nullonwaiting: nullonwebkitfullscreenchange: nullonwebkitfullscreenerror: nullonwheel: nullorigin: "http://localhost:52261"ownerDocument: nullparentElement: nullparentNode: nullplugins: HTMLCollection[0]pointerLockElement: nullpreferredStylesheetSet: nullpreviousSibling: nullreadyState: "complete"referrer: "http://localhost:52261/Default.aspx"rootElement: nullscripts: HTMLCollection[18]scrollingElement: bodyselectedStylesheetSet: nullstyleSheets: StyleSheetListtextContent: nulltitle: "Credit Hire Portal"visibilityState: "visible"vlinkColor: ""webkitCurrentFullScreenElement: nullwebkitFullscreenElement: nullwebkitFullscreenEnabled: truewebkitHidden: falsewebkitIsFullScreen: falsewebkitVisibilityState: "visible"xmlEncoding: nullxmlStandalone: falsexmlVersion: null__proto__: HTMLDocumentlength: 1__proto__: Object[0]
```

Update 1
In the master page I have 2 contentplaceholders, one for navigation bar and the second for a multi step form (in here i have the datetimepicker).
If I put the datetimepicker on the navigation content all is working ... :(

Comment: The script is under the declaration of your js libraries?

Comment: The declaration of the datetimepicker is in head and the script is at the bottom

Comment: have you definitely got an element with id "datetimepicker1" in your page? Are there definitely no errors in the browser console when the page loads? Is the "document.ready" part running? I.e. can you put a console.log just above the call to datetimepicker, to prove the overall function is running?

Comment: all my scripts are in header and this one is on the bottom. No errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

You need to insure that your script under the all the declaration of all the .js(Library files).

Ex.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="Link of other.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

also you can see the error of script in console window of your browser.
**ex. in chrome browser press F12.  and click on console. it will display the error of your script.**

Comment: I'm sure that the order is ok.

Comment: You need to try check the console window that help you if error raise in script.